# Having trouble deleting AWS Amplify projects

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify

I've been working with AWS Amplify to develop an application. In the process I created a few practice projects. From here on out I'll be sticking with one project.
When trying to delete some of the old projects I keep running into issues in the console. The delete execution keeps failing. Does anyone know of a way to force delete these projects?

[here are one of the examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAP8W.png)

Comment: Have you tried logging in to the AWS console and deleting the projects there? If that doesn't work, posting the error output might help to debug the issue.

Comment: Could you give more details why it is failing?
Have you tried deleting in both:
- AWS website: Ampify -> your project -> action -> delete app 
- AWS console: amplify delete (that could have a problem if he loses the reference)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes amplify delete will fail, if it detects drift in AWS Cloudformation.

If you want to delete the project permanently and forcefully use console `AWS  Amplify -> want to delete amplify project -> Actions -> Delete app`.

[image]